Rotate instances after being realized
I have a question which is similar to this one
but with a slightly different setup. I'll attach a file to show what my setup looks like.
After I realize the instances I lose that rotation I had applied for the Instance on Points node. How to regain it afterwards? The ideal is the poles to do that which is shown in the image, that they follow the underlying curve's flow.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Solution mal-function

Edit 2: can't reproduce solution 3



Solution 3: "rotating after" realizing
Since the other proposed solutions don't seem to work:

Solution 1: simplest, doesn't rotate "after" realize.
Solution 2: might behave different in different Blender versions

This solution uses named attributes instead.

Solution file:

There are two objects, one with each solution presented below.

Old solution 1
Anything against making the meshes before instancing?

Old solution 2
If you really need to set it after (I see no reason, but you might have more complex cases), you need to set the center of the rotation.


I just did that and nothing, the poles remain as they are. Question: how are you capturing more than one attribute in the same Capture node? Is it new in 4.2? i'm using 4.1, could that be the issue?
And yes, I have to realize them to further mess with it.

But you can realize "later" (there is a realize node in my solution). To be honest, solution 1 is the best, super easy, and it should work perfectly. There is probably something you missed in the solution. I took your file and put the mesh before the instance, just that. Didn't change rotation or anything.

To capture more attributes, just connect mode attributes to the empty slots.

Added a solution file

The solution is presenting itself to me like the image I added in the question.

@AAAYerus, did you open the file? There are TWO working solutions there.

Yes, that is the second one. Realizing the instances is something that must be done. I've been dodging it for a long time, now I don't have how to escape anymore.

But both solutions ARE realizing instances. (Which is not necessary in the first, but you can do it anyway)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
